# DataGridview duplication of data or not saving new rows to database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, datagridview

I have `DataGridView` in windows Form using C#.

The data is showing successfully and update also being done successfully.

But the problem is with insertion. When I try to insert multiple data into database using Iteration then the it stores 13 times into database because the datagrid initially show 13 records from database. I meant that it stores new rows multiple times(datagridview rows count) into database.

Lets suppose I want to save two rows into databse but it stores 1st row into database 13 times(total number of datagridview rows).

Please check where I am doing mistake

Note: I want to use single datagridview for displaying, update, insert and delete data from database. I have button through which I want to start insertion all new rows to database.

My code is below

```
string connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AuzineConnection"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(connection))
{
    sqlconn.Open();                       
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.IsNewRow)
        {
            using (SqlCommand sqlcomm = sqlconn.CreateCommand())
            {
                 //sqlcomm.CommandText = "Insert into QF (profileID, UserNameLogInName, UserFullName,Email, forumtitle, subtitle, subjecttitle ,noreply, noview , qtags ,Question ,Questiondetails ,questionstatus, qdate,  Status ,todate) values(@status)";
                 sqlcomm.CommandText = "Insert into QF (UserNameLogInName,Status ) values(@UserNameLogInName,@status)";
                 try
                 {                                   
                     sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserNameLogInName", dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["UserNameLogInName"].Value.ToString());
                     sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("Status", dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Status"].Value.ToString());
                     sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                     //MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(RecordIndexNumber.Text)].Cells[Convert.ToInt32(ColInexNum.Text)].Value.ToString());
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                     btnInsert.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

I have tried it `if (!row.IsNewRow)` and it stores only one row. Without it stores multiple unwanted times into database.

I also used `for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)`, but the same issue either it stores one or multiple times.

I just wanted to insert the new rows generated by the user on button click.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserNameLogInName", row.Cells["UserNameLogInName"].Value.ToString());
sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("Status", row.Cells["Status"].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: it gives error... Object refrence not set instance of an object

Comment: The problem is that in foreach block you are always calling the same row (dataGridView1.CurrentRow), and you must to call the row of the foeach statement (row).

Comment: why dont you debug and see where is the error, be sure to know which row throws the exception. Also try using the index of column instead, like this: row.Cells[0]